# C# Winforms: about register machine

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rsa

I am writing a simple application using winforms. After you open the app, you need the register number or you cannot use it. And I also make a register machine to generate register number according to machine code. I ran it on my computer,it worked, however, when I ran it on my friends' computer, when I input the register number which was generated by register machine, it informed me failed. Here is the source code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sMachineCode = Common.GetMachineCode(Common.GetActivatedAdaptorMacAddress());
    string sRegCode = richTextBox1.Text.Trim();
    if (sRegCode == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please input you register number！");
    }else
    {
        if (Common.VerifyRegCode(sMachineCode, sRegCode))
        {
            string sINIFilePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            if (!sINIFilePath.EndsWith("\\"))
            {
                sINIFilePath += "\\";
            }
            sINIFilePath += "option.ini";
            INIFile ini = new INIFile(sINIFilePath);
            ini.WriteStr("RegCode", "regcode", sRegCode);
            MessageBox.Show("registe successfully！Please restar your application！");
            Cef.Shutdown();
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fail to registe！Please check your register number！");
        }
    }
}




public static bool VerifyRegCode(string sMachineCode, string sRegCode)
{
    bool bResult = false;
    if (sMachineCode != "" && sRegCode != "")
    {
        if (sMachineCode.Length % 4 != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }else
        {
            string sPubKey = "";
            byte[] bMachineCode = (new UnicodeEncoding()).GetBytes(sMachineCode);
            byte[] bRegCode = Convert.FromBase64String(sRegCode);
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            sPubKey = "****";
            rsa.FromXmlString(sPubKey);
            RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter rsaD = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(rsa);
            rsaD.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
            SHA1Managed sha1= new SHA1Managed();
            byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(bMachineCode);
            bResult=rsaD.VerifySignature(hash,bRegCode);     
            return bResult;
        }
    }
    return bResult;
}




private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sMachineCode = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    string sRegCode;
    byte[] bRegCode;
    byte[] bMachineCode = (new UnicodeEncoding()).GetBytes(sMachineCode);
    if (sMachineCode == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("请输入机器码！");
    }else
    {   
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        string sPriKey = "*****";
        rsa.FromXmlString(sPriKey);
        RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter f = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa);
        f.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
        SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(bMachineCode);
        bRegCode = f.CreateSignature(hash);
        sRegCode = Convert.ToBase64String(bRegCode);
        richTextBox1.Text = sRegCode;
    }        
}
```

Comment: seems your key is based on machine code?

Comment: yes! I convert the mac address into machine code

Comment: did the user copy the machine code to you?

Comment: Yes, I copy the machine code from the user. App ran successfully on computer A and B, but failed in computer C. I wander may be the rsa algorithm not worked on computer C

Comment: 1. make sure you encryption and verification work ok by some **Unit Test** 2. make sure the machine code are really the same before and after copy

Comment: what is unit test 2? I am sure the machine code is right.

Comment: if no unit test how can you be so sure?

Comment: @shiyan when something fails *and you don't know why*... then you immediately need to **stop being sure of anything**, and start testing

Comment: OK, I will try Unit Test.